# Loading another fragment in a fragment not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Im trying to load a fragment in another fragment. But the layout is not loading. I put a toast message in the second fragment , that appears but the layout does not change. This is a navigation view. So basically i dont want to start a new activity. I always want the navigation view to appear but i need many screes to appear based on button click

I'm trying to replace the courseFragment with the lessonfragment.

The code in the courseFragment is:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.coursefragment, new lessonFragment(), 
"NewFragmentTag");
            ft.commit();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

The code of the fees fragment is:

```
public class lessonFragment extends Fragment {

ViewGroup rootView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.cours, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You open lesson",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Lessons");
}
```

}

CourseFragment xml called fragmnet_course.xml

```
  LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#04182f"
android:id="@+id/coursefragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.apple.project4.CoursesFragment" />
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/lesson0"
    android:background="@color/one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Lessons0">

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/lesson2"
    android:background="@color/one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Lessons1"/>
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/lesson2"
    android:text="Lessonsq2"/>
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/teachertraining"
    android:text="Training of Teachers"/>
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/one"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/childrenscourse"
    android:text="Children's courses"/>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

We should use `getChildFragmentManager()` to replace fragments inside a fragment

Replace `getFragmentManager()` with `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.coursefragment, new lessonFragment(), "NewFragmentTag");
ft.commit();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your getFragmentManager() with getChildFragmentManager().
Because if you want to open a child fragment from a fragment then you need to use child Fragment manager.